# Comparing 2 sinusoids: Discrete case vs Continuous case

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals

I'm doing MIT's OCW course with Allan Oppenheim - "Signals and Systems".

I'm given 2 continuous signals$$x(t)=\cos[\omega_x(t+r_x)+\theta_x]\tag1$$ and $$y(t)=\cos[\omega_y(t+r_y)+\theta_y]\tag2$$

Assuming their phases are the same, the notes tell me that the signals are identical if $$\omega_x=\omega_y$$which is quite obvious.

Now, the discrete case:

Again, I'm given 2 signals $$x[n]=\cos[\Omega_x(n+P_x)+\theta_x]\tag3$$ and $$y[n]=\cos[\Omega_y(n+P_y)+\theta_y]\tag4$$

This time, assuming that the phases are the same, the notes say that the signals are identical if $$\Omega_x=\Omega_y+2\pi k \tag5$$

Why is the $2\pi k$ present in equation 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the $2\pi$-periodicity of the cosine and the discrete nature of $n$ ($n,k\in \mathbb{N}$):
$$
x[n] = \cos[\Omega_\mathrm{x}] = \cos[(\Omega_\mathrm{y}+2\pi k)n] = \cos[\Omega_\mathrm{y}n+2\pi kn] = \cos[\Omega_\mathrm{y}n] = y[n]
$$
This important "phenomenon" is called aliasing and only occurs for discrete-time signals. The normalized frequency $\Omega$ is therefore usually restricted to the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: In case Deve's answer isn't clear enough: the issue is that you need $x(t) = y(t)$ to be true in the continuous case for ALL values of $t$, but you only need $x[n] = y[n]$ to be true for $n$ being an integer. That introduces the ambiguity in the frequency (the $+2\pi k$ term).